# Writing my first book

Tags: books, book-design, mathematics

I am writing my first book ever, an undergraduate mathematics textbook, and even though I'm halfway done with the content, I'm still using a really simple template I found on the internet that uses the extarticle class and the amsmath package. Now the problem is, I would like to change the style of my book to make it more easier to read, I would like something similar to the GTM series (For example Ziemer's Modern Real Analysis or Diestel's Graph Theory textbooks), but I'm a beginner in LateX, so I don't know how to do that.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Not everybody knows the GTM se ries, could you please add an example?

Comment: Sorry prod you further, but it would be helpful if you could describe the typographic features you'd like (and maybe add images to your question). Which elements exactly would you like to have styled in which way, etc.?

Answer (score 5):

I wanted to provide this as a comment but for some reason SE won't let me comment.

I have no idea how you want your book to be styled. I suggest that you look at the `memoir` class manual (Warning: I developed the class). This is a superset of the `book` class (if you are writing a book why use an `article` class?). It provides examples of a book publication and one for a thesis.

You might also find my *A Few Notes on Book Design* (`> texdoc memdesign`) of some use.

Comment: I am also using `memoir` class. It's great.

Answer (score 2):

This is very generic question you asked. I suggest you from my experience to follow the following steps below:

1. First, prepare your content as a whole book.
2. Then type-set the content using LaTeX.
3. When you are facing to type set any part of your book just ask the particular question explaining in details with minimal code. Others can understand it and propose a solution.
4. Apply the solution to your LaTeX code and see if it is as like your plan.

This way of writing a book worked for me. You may try. Please don't approach with generic query.

Good wishes for your book!

As @Teepeemm's advice tells you that you should know basic type settings knowledge in LaTeX what can be gained by reading any LaTeX book or or [LaTeX wiki book](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX) or [Overleaf documentation](https://www.overleaf.com/learn) etc. Overall, a great source of learning LaTeX is https://www.learnlatex.org/en/. You can try this only. Thanks @Skillmon for the recommendation.

Comment: But I would suggest enough familiarity with LaTeX and defining commands so that you can separate the content from the styling.  Lots of `\textbf{3.1 My Section Title}` will be lots more work to change than `\section{My Section Title}`.

Comment: I wouldn't suggest the LaTeX wiki book. Sadly it is in part outdated and overall not in good shape. Instead, for a quick course to learn the basics of LaTeX I'd suggest reading through learnlatex.org.

Comment: @Skillmon That's a good resource. I forgot about it and just added.