# Converting a book to LaTeX

Tags: book-design

Just to pass some time, I've decided that I want to convert my math textbook and remake it entirely (or how much ever I can manage to complete in a few months) in LaTeX. Are there any things I need to look out for, any good tutorials or resources I can use? Tips are extremely welcome. The book already has a pdf version, but it's not very well formatted.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE, if you are a beginner, I'd start with this: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/583/101651.

Comment: Either what @CarLaTeX suggested, or to get at least a basic overview take a look at [LearnLaTeX.org](https://www.learnlatex.org/).

Comment: I am familiar with most of the beginner to intermediate level commands; I need help specifically with this use case.

Comment: General piece of advice: Concentrate on the contents first, and strictly use semantic mark up. Then you can easily reformat stuff later on. Even if you just use stubs. For instance: I'll need a specific variable type often, and it might need to be formatted in a specific way, then I'd use `\newcommand\mytypethingy[1]{#1}` and use that throughout my sources. If I then decide that all thingies should be bold I can simply change the definition.

Comment: Related question: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/625818/writing-my-first-book

Comment: you need to start and then if you have any tex questions make a small example of the specific problem and ask for help. Your question is really too general for the question and answer format of this site.